# How did it get converted into 1 line of code from 3 lines? Remapping uv and fixing aspect ratio in shaders

Tags: math, vector, glsl, shader, vec

How would you get from this

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy; // <0, 1>
uv -= 0.5; // <-0.5,0.5>
uv.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y; // fix aspect ratio
```

to this?

```
vec2 uv = (fragCoord - .5 * iResolution.xy) / iResolution.y; // Condense 3 lines down to a single line!
```

Well, I tried breaking it down into components

((fragCoord.x-0.5) / iResolution.x) * (iResolution.x / iResolution.y)

((fragCoord.y-0.5) / iResolution.y)

Comment: Why would you need to? Other than "harder to read", which is the opposite of useful, what problem with the three lines does the one-liner solve?

Comment: I'm just curious how it got compressed into 1 line. Well, one-liner uses one division less. (which I think is good?)

Comment: It didn't, they do different things. The three lines fix the aspect ratio by scaling only `x` at the end, the one-liner scales the entire vec2 based on `y` so it changes _both_ `x` and `y`, with `y` becoming 1.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's actually not true. Both snippets are equivalent. See the derivation in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's add a 4th line:

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
uv -= 0.5;
uv.x *= iResolution.x/iResolution.y;
uv.y *= iResolution.y/iResolution.y;
```

Notice that `iResolution.y/iResolution.y == 1`, so the line we added changes nothing. However, it opens the possibility to simplify the code. We can now combine the 3rd and the 4th line by operating on two-component vectors:

```
vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;
uv -= 0.5;
uv *= iResolution.xy/iResolution.y;
```

Combining it all together into one algebraic expression turns it into:

```
vec2 uv = (fragCoord/iResolution.xy - 0.5)*iResolution.xy/iResolution.y;
```

Now we can move `iResolution.xy` inside the parentheses (distributive law of multiplication):

```
vec2 uv = (fragCoord/iResolution.xy*iResolution.xy - 0.5*iResolution.xy)/iResolution.y;
```

And, of course, dividing `fragCoord` by `iResolution.xy` cancels out with multiplying it by `iResolution.xy`, so we arrive at the one liner you had:

```
vec2 uv = (fragCoord - 0.5*iResolution.xy)/iResolution.y;
```